# How do I display user input using document.getElementById() from one webpage on another using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies, getelementbyid

I am trying to record user input in `listing.html` in order to display it on my main page `index.html`. To do this, I am using a function I wrote, namely `submitValue()` with a nested function `addListing()`.

listing.html:

```
<h3>
Timer: <input id="myTimer">
<p>
Question: <input id="myQuestion"> 
<p>
Bounty: <input id="myBounty">
</h3>

<button onclick="submitValue()"> Submit </button> 
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

`submitValue()` is located in `index.js` (where I initially planned to write all of my javascript code).

```
function submitValue() {
    var t = document.getElementById("myTimer").value;
    var q  = document.getElementById("myQuestion").value;
    var b = document.getElementById("myBounty").value;
    location.href='index.html';
    addListing('#f38181', t, q, b);
}
```

The problem I have encountered is that the function `document.getElementById()` refers automatically to the main page (which in my case is `index.html`). The divs `"myTimer"`, `"myQuestion"`, and `"myBounty"` are located on `listing.html` however. This is inconvenient for my purposes as, once again, I'm trying to display the user input (value) from these divs on `index.html`. 
I've read several forum posts that vaguely hinted at using AJAX and JQuery, as well as `document.cookie`. I'm open to trying any approach as long as it works.
If you've made it through all this preamble, then my question is as follows: How do I solve this annoying problem?

Answer (score 0):

The data you retrieve fro the listing.html does not persist if you call another page, in your case **index.html**.
     In order to achieve the result you have to persist the data you get from the fields.To persist the data either you can use a db from server or you can use local storage from browser.

In chrome you can try this.

```html
function submitValue() {
    var t = document.getElementById("myTimer").value;
    var q  = document.getElementById("myQuestion").value;
    var b = document.getElementById("myBounty").value;
    localStorage.setItem("#f38181",JSON.stringify({ t, q, b}))
    location.href='index.html';
}
```

And in the index.html retrieve the data like this

```html
var listingdata = localStorage.getItem("#f38181");
var data = JSON.parse(listingdata);
console.log(listingdata)
```

Comment: #f38181 is the css color I picked. It's not something I would need to save. 
`var t = document.getElementById("myTimer").value;
    var q  = document.getElementById("myQuestion").value;
    var b = document.getElementById("myBounty").value;` can't be kept either. They don't allow my code to run any further since index.html does not contain the divs "myTimer", "myQuestion", and "myBounty". I'm not sure you've understood my question, but thanks for suggesting localStorage as another option to try.

Comment: Then user a fixed key to store the data in browser as stated above then retrieve it in main html.

Comment: You need two separate script to achieve this. One script in listing.html and another script in index.html.

Comment: How would I do that? Should I use localStorage?

Comment: yes In listing.html  First save all the data in local storage.
put the retrieve script on document onload event of index.html to display the results

Comment: Didn't work since without the document method I have no way to record user input.